# Making scroll bar stick to bottom of page in angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

So I have a table that has a lot of content in it. The problem is that we want to allow the user to be able to scroll horizontally on the table but, because of the amount of content, they have to scroll a lot to reach the bottom of the table to interact with the scroll bar. Is there a way in angular using a directive for me to achieve having the scroll bar for the table to sit at the bottom of the window/screen not the bottom of the table?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-ngea1h?embed=1&file=home/home.html

Comment: Provide a stackblitz please .

Comment: @selemmn I made a stackblitz i just dont know how to get you the link...

Comment: Then it is `AngularJs` not `Angular` ..

Comment: @selemmn yes, I made a stackblitz but I do not know how to link it to you. When I click share it gives me a generic link

Comment: Merely copy the url and add it to your question, I'd made an edit and removed the `angular` tag since it is misleading.

Comment: You should fork that link before, or create a new project starting from here http://stackblitz.com, not from an other aleady created project.

Comment: @selemmn link posted

Comment: I do not see any problem in that, also , you did not use `fixedScroll` there. And I do not think i can help you a lot with that , and more `angular` than `angularjs` :(

Comment: @selemmn well the problem is that I dont want to make the user scroll all the way down to the scroll bar. I was hoping there was a way to have the scroll bar sit at the bottom of the window